# XMLWriter error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty

Tags: php, mysql, xml

i'm trying to get records from users table on MySQL, then save it on a randomly generated name xml file. so i have this code on my php:

```
<?php 
    include_once ("connect.php");
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $length = 10;
    $randomString   = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);
    $savedstring    = $randomString;
    $sql            = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $query          = mysql_query($sql);
    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openURI($savedstring . '.xml');
    $xml->startDocument("1.0");
    $xml->setIndent(true);
    $xml->startElement('users');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $xml->startElement("user");
        $xml->writeAttribute('username', $row['username']);
        $xml->writeRaw($row['password']);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    header('Content-type: text/xml');
    $xml->endDocument();
    $xml->flush();
    echo $savedstring;
?>
```

but it gets me error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty, any hints on which part i'm doing it wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: when you use `header('Content-type: text/xml');` you have to actually output XML which you don't do in your question. What is your concrete question then?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It would seem you're trying to write/read an empty XML document.

You can catch such an error with the following:

```
$xml = file_get_contents("/some/xml/file.xml");
if (trim($xml) == '') {
    echo 'Empty XML file!';
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Comment: thanks! after checking with that code, it turns that the file isn't empty at all, when i tried to look up on the server, the file's generated with the content that i want.

Comment: Great! If my answer was useful you might consider accepting the answer as correct for future visitors. :)